# JS как передать данные на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript, cookie, redirect, localstorage

На странице #1 я получаю ответ от севера - хэш сессий. Если все ок, редирект на другую страницу, но проблема в том что JS отрабатывается на одной странице, а этот хэш нужен уже на другой странице. Можно использовать куки, но мне кажется в плане безопасности их можно спокойно украсть...

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, самым простым было бы использование local storage, но Вы о нём знаете, если включили в теги.

Значит, вы хотите другое решение.

Можно включить их в URL при совершении редиректа - но в плане безопасности это ничуть не лучше.

Ну, и можно на другой странице заново их запросить - хуже в плане производительности, так как два раза обращаемся к серверу с одним и тем же запросом, и, кроме того, можно напрямую зайти на эту страницу, и тогда не сработает проверка "всё ок".

В общем, как то так.

По совокупности недостатков всё же local storage - лучшее решение

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `localStorage` или `sessionStorage`.

У `sessionStorage` время жизни вкладки.

Тогда в разных вкладках может быть разная сессия.

Правда есть еще дублирование вкладок.